# Can't get linebreak in react native

Tags: css, react-native

I am trying to get a line break between name and birth, address and streetAdress, and email and number. Name, adress, and email should stay on the same line as the icons. It is probably not difficult but I can't wrap my head around it.

```js
const persons = {
    name: " Linda Hansen",
    birth: "01.01.2002",
    address: "  Dalen 24",
    streetAddress: "Leikanger 6863",
    email: "  Linda.Hansen@gmail.com",
    number: "12345678",
};

export default function UserInfo() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.centerContainer}>
            <Image source={{ uri: uri[0].userIcon }} style={styles.profileIcon} />
            <View style={styles.userInfoContainer}>
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                <Icon name="user" size={40} ></Icon>
                </View>
                <Text style= {styles.textStyle}> {persons.name} </Text>
                <Text style={styles.textStyleSmall}> {persons.birth} </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.userInfoContainer}>
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                    <Icon name="home" size={40} ></Icon>
                </View>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{persons.address}</Text>
                <Text style={styles.textStyleSmall}>{persons.streetAddress}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.userInfoContainer}>
                <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                    <Icon name="phone" size={40} ></Icon>
                </View>
                <Text style = {styles.textStyle}> {persons.email}</Text>
                <Text style = {styles.textStyleSmall}>{persons.number} </Text>
            </View>
```

CSS:

```css
userInfoContainer: {
      width: "100%",
      borderBottomColor: "gray",
      borderBottomWidth: 1,
      backgroundColor: "yellow",
      flexDirection: "row",
```

It looks like this at the moment:

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for line break,
`<Text>Hello~{“\n}This is a drill </Text>`

Comment: I can't get that to work when I use const in the text element!

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function UserInfo() {
return (
    <View style={styles.centerContainer}>
    <Image source={{ uri: uri[0].userIcon }} style={styles.profileIcon} />


        <View style={styles.userInfoContainer}>
            <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
            <Icon name="user" size={40} ></Icon>
            </View>
            <Text style= {styles.textStyle}> {persons.name}{“\n”} </Text>
            <Text style={styles.textStyleSmall}> {persons.birth} </Text>
        </View>



        <View style={styles.userInfoContainer}>
            <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                <Icon name="home" size={40} ></Icon>
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{persons.address}{“\n”}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textStyleSmall}>{persons.streetAddress}</Text>
        </View>



        <View style={styles.userInfoContainer}>
            <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
                <Icon name="phone" size={40} ></Icon>
            </View>
            <Text style = {styles.textStyle}> {persons.email}{“\n”}</Text>
            <Text style = {styles.textStyleSmall}>{persons.number} </Text>
        </View>
```

Comment: you can leave a github repo of your project and i m gonna check it

Answer (score 0):

you can try it with flex

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
 <Icon name="user" size={40} />
 <View>
  <Text> {persons.name}</Text>
  <Text>{persons.birth} </Text>
 </View>
</View>
```